# Why is my worker node kubelet service not starting?. kubelet[8094]: Insecure values: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-22.04, aws-ec2

Following Kelsey Hightower's KTHW on AWS EC2 instances and got to boot strapping the worker nodes and somehow kubelet seems to be fubarred.
NOT USING KUBEADM or DOCKER.

Getting the following error now.

```
kubelet.service - Kubernetes Kubelet
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-01-14 18:54:09 UTC; 86ms ago
       Docs: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes
    Process: 8094 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/kubelet --config=/var/lib/kubelet/kubelet-config.yaml --container-runtime=remote --container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock --image-pull-progress-deadline=2m --kube>
   Main PID: 8094 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 171ms

Jan 14 18:54:09 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[8094]:                 Insecure values: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_A>
Jan 14 18:54:09 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[8094]:       --tls-min-version string                                   Minimum TLS version supported. Possible values: VersionTLS10, VersionTLS11, VersionTLS12, VersionTLS13 (DEPRECATED: This paramet>
Jan 14 18:54:09 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[8094]:       --tls-private-key-file string                              File containing x509 private key matching --tls-cert-file. (DEPRECATED: This parameter should be set via the config file specifi>
Jan 14 18:54:09 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[8094]:       --topology-manager-policy string                           Topology Manager policy to use. Possible values: 'none', 'best-effort', 'restricted', 'single-numa-node'. (default "none") (DEPR>
Jan 14 18:54:09 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[8094]:       --topology-manager-scope string                            Scope to which topology hints applied. Topology Manager collects hints from Hint Providers and applies them to defined scope to >
Jan 14 18:54:09 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[8094]:   -v, --v Level                                                  number for the log level verbosity (default 0)
Jan 14 18:54:09 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[8094]:       --version version[=true]                                   Print version information and quit
Jan 14 18:54:09 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[8094]:       --vmodule moduleSpec                                       comma-separated list of pattern=N settings for file-filtered logging
Jan 14 18:54:09 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[8094]:       --volume-plugin-dir string                                 The full path of the directory in which to search for additional third party volume plugins (default "/usr/libexec/kubernetes/ku>
Jan 14 18:54:09 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[8094]:       --volume-stats-agg-period duration                         Specifies interval for kubelet to calculate and cache the volume disk usage for all pods and volumes.  To disable volume calcula
```

```
sudo journalctl -xeu kubelet
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --seccomp-profile-root string                              <Warning: Alpha feature> Directory path for seccomp profiles. (default "/var/lib/kubelet/seccomp") (DEPRECATED: will be removed in 1.23, in favor of using the `<root-dir>/seccomp` directory)
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --serialize-image-pulls                                    Pull images one at a time. We recommend *not* changing the default value on nodes that run docker daemon with version < 1.9 or an Aufs storage backend. Issue #10959 has more details. (default true) (DEPRECATED: This parameter should be set>
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --skip-headers                                             If true, avoid header prefixes in the log messages
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --skip-log-headers                                         If true, avoid headers when opening log files
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --stderrthreshold severity                                 logs at or above this threshold go to stderr (default 2)
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --storage-driver-buffer-duration duration                  Writes in the storage driver will be buffered for this duration, and committed to the non memory backends as a single transaction (default 1m0s) (DEPRECATED: This is a cadvisor flag that was mistakenly registered with the Kubelet. Due to l>
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --storage-driver-db string                                 database name (default "cadvisor") (DEPRECATED: This is a cadvisor flag that was mistakenly registered with the Kubelet. Due to legacy concerns, it will follow the standard CLI deprecation timeline before being removed.)
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --storage-driver-host string                               database host:port (default "localhost:8086") (DEPRECATED: This is a cadvisor flag that was mistakenly registered with the Kubelet. Due to legacy concerns, it will follow the standard CLI deprecation timeline before being removed.)
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --storage-driver-password string                           database password (default "root") (DEPRECATED: This is a cadvisor flag that was mistakenly registered with the Kubelet. Due to legacy concerns, it will follow the standard CLI deprecation timeline before being removed.)
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --storage-driver-secure                                    use secure connection with database (DEPRECATED: This is a cadvisor flag that was mistakenly registered with the Kubelet. Due to legacy concerns, it will follow the standard CLI deprecation timeline before being removed.)
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --storage-driver-table string                              table name (default "stats") (DEPRECATED: This is a cadvisor flag that was mistakenly registered with the Kubelet. Due to legacy concerns, it will follow the standard CLI deprecation timeline before being removed.)
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --storage-driver-user string                               database username (default "root") (DEPRECATED: This is a cadvisor flag that was mistakenly registered with the Kubelet. Due to legacy concerns, it will follow the standard CLI deprecation timeline before being removed.)
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --streaming-connection-idle-timeout duration               Maximum time a streaming connection can be idle before the connection is automatically closed. 0 indicates no timeout. Example: '5m' (default 4h0m0s) (DEPRECATED: This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's >
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --sync-frequency duration                                  Max period between synchronizing running containers and config (default 1m0s) (DEPRECATED: This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/k>
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --system-cgroups string                                    Optional absolute name of cgroups in which to place all non-kernel processes that are not already inside a cgroup under '/'. Empty for no container. Rolling back the flag requires a reboot. (DEPRECATED: This parameter should be set via the>
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --system-reserved mapStringString                          A set of ResourceName=ResourceQuantity (e.g. cpu=200m,memory=500Mi,ephemeral-storage=1Gi) pairs that describe resources reserved for non-kubernetes components. Currently only cpu and memory are supported. See http://kubernetes.io/docs/user>
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --system-reserved-cgroup string                            Absolute name of the top level cgroup that is used to manage non-kubernetes components for which compute resources were reserved via '--system-reserved' flag. Ex. '/system-reserved'. [default=''] (DEPRECATED: This parameter should be set v>
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --tls-cert-file string                                     File containing x509 Certificate used for serving HTTPS (with intermediate certs, if any, concatenated after server cert). If --tls-cert-file and --tls-private-key-file are not provided, a self-signed certificate and key are generated for >
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --tls-cipher-suites strings                                Comma-separated list of cipher suites for the server. If omitted, the default Go cipher suites will be used.
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:                 Preferred values: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY>
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:                 Insecure values: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA. (DEPRECATED: This parameter should be set via the config file spec>
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --tls-min-version string                                   Minimum TLS version supported. Possible values: VersionTLS10, VersionTLS11, VersionTLS12, VersionTLS13 (DEPRECATED: This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/t>
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --tls-private-key-file string                              File containing x509 private key matching --tls-cert-file. (DEPRECATED: This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/>
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --topology-manager-policy string                           Topology Manager policy to use. Possible values: 'none', 'best-effort', 'restricted', 'single-numa-node'. (default "none") (DEPRECATED: This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://>
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:       --topology-manager-scope string                            Scope to which topology hints applied. Topology Manager collects hints from Hint Providers and applies them to defined scope to ensure the pod admission. Possible values: 'container', 'pod'. (default "container") (DEPRECATED: This paramete>
Jan 14 19:06:13 CKATRAINWK2 kubelet[9116]:   -v, --v Level                                                  number for the log level verbosity (default 0)
```

tried soo many numerous things including

- specifying the cgroups as systemd in the kubelet-config.yaml
- retracing my steps through the guide to make sure I didn't miss anything.
- upgrading components like containerd to 1.4.4 , runc 1.1.7, cni-plugins 1.1.0

(side note) crictl is experiencing issues as well.

Just need guidance on troubleshooting.